# Find common keys of a number of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have around 20000 dictionaries.I want find all the keys which are common in all the dictionary(that key need to be present in all 20000) dictionary.How can I achieve this.Currently I am writing something like that,But its not giving me the desired result:

```
if parsedData.keys() not in uniquelist: 
            uniquelist.append(parsedData.keys())
        else:
            commonlist.append(parsedData.keys())
```

here parsed data is my dictionary. Please help me with this.

Comment: what does parsedData look like? does it contain all you dictionary files?

Answer (score 5):

You could create the set of the keys in the first dictionary and then in a loop form the intersection with the remaining keys:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
>>> d2 = {'b':4, 'c':7,'d':5}
>>> d3 = {'b':5, 'c':8,'e':6}
>>> dicts = [d1,d2,d3]
>>> common_keys = set(d1.keys())
>>> for d in dicts[1:]:
    common_keys.intersection_update(set(d.keys()))

>>> common_keys
{'b', 'c'}
```

Comment: This is what I would do if I wasn't obsessed with comprehensions. My solution essentially does this, but in a one liner.  This is easier to understand, admittedly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `Counter` from the `collections` module For instance:

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter()
for dictionary in listOfAllDictionaries:
    count = count+Counter(dictionary)
uniquelist = [key for key in count if count[key] == 1]
commonlist = [key for key in count if count[key] > 1]
```

Comment: I would not use Counter, it is a lot of overhead just to test existence.

Comment: It looks like he wants both the unique elements and the common elements. The solutions with `sets` appear to ignore that.

Comment: Though you may be right: he does only ask for common elements.

Comment: He only asked for common, but I'll edit my answer to do unique as well. Again I think sets are most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way about it, but it uses only common, easy to understand operators and methods.  Simply create a list of all the keys, and count the ones that show up as many times as you have dictionaries

```
>>> d1 = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
>>> d2 = {3: 'c', 2: 'b'}
>>> dictionaries = [d1, d2]
>>> for d in dictionaries:
    keys += list(d.keys())

>>> keys
[1, 2, 2, 3]

>>> commonkeys = []
>>> for k in keys:
    if k not in commonkeys and keys.count(k) == len(dictionaries):
        commonkeys += [k]

>>> commonkeys
[2]
```

voila, the common key among the dictionaries was 2.

Comment: This works, but for so many dicts that he has, you are uneccessary storing a potentially large list of non-unique keys. I think this is a lessor solution to one using sets

Comment: Agreed.  Using sets is about two orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 0):

A Pythonic way, not necessarily the most understandable. Neverthheless, here is the one liner:

```
>>> d1 = { 'a' : 1, 'b' : 1 }
>>> d2 = { 'a' : 1, }
>>> d3 = { 'a' : 1, 'c' : 1 }
>>> set.intersection(*tuple(set(d.keys()) for d in [d1, d2, d3]))

set(['a'])
```

Unlike the solutions that are using Counters and Lists, this should be pretty efficient and low overhead going through so many dicts. This does build a large tuple, however, and for that reason, I would suspect that the more efficient code would be to loop through it.

It was mentioned that you might want "unique" keys as well, but I'm not sure what means. Does that mean, just not common, or does that mean, only in one dict?  If it is the former, then just also keep a set that is the union, not the intersection, then take the difference of the two when you are done. Depending on the total number of unique keys we are talking about, I still think this is a relatively cheap operation.

Edit:
To answer question below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

all_dicts = [d1, d2, d3]
common = set.intersection(*tuple(set(d.keys()) for d in all_dicts))

common_key_values = defaultdict(list)
for d in all_dicts:
    for key in common:
        common_key_values.append(d[key])
```

Comment: Thank yo so much,Its working exactly the same way I wanted.

Comment: if i want to retrieve all the values of the common key from each dictionary how should i manipulate the code?

Comment: I'll edit my answer but in the future be nice and award the answer, then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Pinching John Coleman's [example dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049438/753731)

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
d2 = {'b':4, 'c':7,'d':5}
d3 = {'b':5, 'c':8,'e':6}
d = [d1, d2, d3]
d = iter(d)
reduce(set.intersection, d, set(next(d)))
set(['c', 'b'])
```